# Can I control WCF Tracing programmatically?

Tags: .net, wcf, trace

I recently read [Chris Love's advice on using WCF Tracing to help with troubleshooting](http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2010/09/02/Turn-on-WCF-Tracing-for-WCF-Troubleshooting.aspx).
He turns on the tracing by adding new sections of XML to the `app.config` file and I have since seen [similar recommendations here for the same technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing).

However we don't really want to ship multiple `app.config` files.
And we definitely don't want our customers modifying them on production systems!

**Is there a way that the various settings for WCF Tracing can be set up in the app.config, but the tracing is turned on/off from code?**

Ideally I'd like my application to check the registry and only activate the tracing when a certain value was present.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34283667/187650 

you can enable it using wmi, see link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My suggestion is to use a custom `TraceFilter` which you apply to all listeners attached to the WCF TraceSources (i.e., "System.ServiceModel", "System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"). Inside the TraceFilter's `ShouldTrace()` method you can then conditionally suppress tracing based on any information that's available to the app.

Here is some sample code which you could use as a starting point. There is a static helper class which determines globally and once during the lifetime of an app whether tracing should be enabled or disabled:

```
namespace WCF.Diagnostics
{
    using System.Diagnostics;

    public static class WcfDiagnosticsHelper
    {
        private readonly static bool _shouldTraceWcf;

        static WcfDiagnosticsHelper()
        {
            // here, determine if WCF Tracing should be enabled or not
            // i.e., read some custom settings from App.config or the registry etc...

            _shouldTraceWcf = true;
        }

        internal static bool ShouldTraceWcf
        {
            get { return _shouldTraceWcf; }
        }
    }

    public class WcfTraceFilter : TraceFilter
    {
        public override bool ShouldTrace(TraceEventCache cache, string source, TraceEventType eventType, int id, string formatOrMessage, object[] args, object data1, object[] data)
        {
            // In here, check the static 'ShouldTraceWcf' property as well as the name of the originating TraceSource
            if (source != null && source.StartsWith("System.ServiceModel") && !WcfDiagnosticsHelper.ShouldTraceWcf)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

In the App.config you'd configure the TraceFilter like this:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" propagateActivity="true" switchValue="Warning">
      <listeners>
        <add name="LocalXmlFile" initializeData="WcfTracing.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener">
          <filter type="WCF.Diagnostics.WcfTraceFilter, WCF_Custom_TraceFilter"/>
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

**

Please note that a similar behavior could be achieved by writing a custom [Trace Switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.switch.aspx). The main difference would be that a TraceSwitch is applied to a TraceSource, and a TraceFilter to a TraceListener. It would be slightly more involved, though.

Comment: Excellent answer. This is pretty close to what I need, but for some reason the log file still seems to grow even when I set `_shouldTraceWcf` to false.

Comment: That sounds strange. Could you post the `<system.diagnostics>` section of your app.config?

Comment: The `<system.diagnostics>` was as you describe but with a second entry for `System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging` writing to a separate file. And a `<system.serviceModel><diagnostics><messageLogging>` section turning on the message logging. Both used the same `TraceFilter` - the messagelogging one switched off (the file was created but stayed 0 bytes) but the `ServiceModel` was still populated.

Comment: I've abandoned work on this for now and just made it as easy as possible for the clients/field engineers to edit the app.config (using named `<sharedListener>` entries so all they need to do is uncomment the `<add name="myListener">` entry in the `<listeners>` section).
I'm awarding you the bounty as you got me the closest to the solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to a question about doing something similar.  The guy that asked the question seemed to have some programmatic control over WCF tracing working, but not all.  I don't if he ever got it working to his satisfaction or not.

[WCF tracing in code does not follow MessageLogging settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180789/wcf-tracing-in-code-does-not-follow-messagelogging-settings/4185651#4185651)

Maybe it will help you, maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

WCF tracing is plugging into the System.Diagnostics classes that have been in .NET for a long time. There is an API for anything done in xml. For example [Create and Initialize Trace Listeners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

For the general overview scroll to the bottom of the [Trace class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) documentation.